# Ubuntu Screen Mirror | Display Settings - Display mode not available

Tags: display, mirrors, screencast

I visited many solutions regarding Mirroring and Casting even HDMI solutions.
I actually know how to connect to a screen using display mode: mirror in Ubuntu 16.04.
But I am not able to find the option of Display mode in uUbuntu 18.04.

Here is a screenshot that shows the issue I am having:

[image]